# Elastic search runtime metrics

Tags: elasticsearch

My question is more research related.

We have elastic search handling various tasks including taking log entries from remote clients. The problem is that there are times that the clients overload elastic search.

Is there a way to query ES to get runtime metrics like number of queries in last n minutes and so on. I'm hoping we can use these to throttle the client logging as load increases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Data on number of search and get requests per second can be obtained by querying [indices stats](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-stats.html).

There are [multiple tools](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/community/current/health.html) that provide elasticsearch monitoring, most of them open-source. Having a look at their source code may be helpful.

Please also note that throttling requests client-side based on elasticsearch stats may not be optimal solution, as it is hard to coordinate with variable number of clients. Using circuit breakers that trigger on request timeouts may be more robust.

Also an option is to set a reverse proxy in front of elasticsearch. Moreoever, some problems related to many indexing requests can be solved by throttling IO for merge operations in elasticsearch itself, as is discussed [here](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/index-modules-store.html#store-throttling).

Answer (score -1):

Try using LucidWorks SiLK instead - it uses Solr and that's more scalable.  Download it from here:  http://www.lucidworks.com/lucidworks-silk